# Which are the J2ME MVC frameworks?

Tags: model-view-controller, blackberry, java-me

I have to do a quite big project in J2ME for school.
I didn't used 'till now J2ME, so are there J2ME MVC frameworks
for which I can find books or at least very good online tutorials?
MVC is what I'm looking for because we have to do unit testing and
I'm familiar with MVC from ASP.Net MVC, Rails and Grails.

So, any good framework to use with this project?
We are developing this project for Blackberry cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only, the fact is that every handset is very different - its extremely difficult to build an app that spans all the major J2ME-capable handsets that looks half way decent by following the basic principles. Which is why we end up doing things like using sprite based fonts (ugh). I don't think I've *ever* worked a mobile project using J2ME where we've managed to stick to just the standard J2ME (and, we try very hard). Even things that should be standard, like reading a JSON feed from a server, persistent storage or even really simple things like sprite rotation is really not very standard at all (yes, I'm looking at you RIM). And, then throw a requirement for Android into the mix and you're done.

I've used Polish, and its really very good. Commercial license is not cheap (but worth it), but for a school project its free. Flash (cough) is also a good alternative too. These days, personally, I find my projects need to span iPhone (Objective-C), Android (Java), Nokia (J2ME) and Blackberry (pseudo-J2ME) and it gets real tricky to not use a commercial framework (or roll your own, if you've the time and inclination). I'm open to ideas for frameworks that span all those platforms?

Comment: Circling back to this comment, I've really started to like building apps using HTML using PhoneGap or Titanium. You need to invest a lot of time making your app zippy enough to compete with real native apps, but its cross-browser appeal makes it worth it (I'm still on the fence, but I like the direction this is heading).

Answer (score 2):

With Java you don't really need a framework, creating MVC-based apps is just about using the principles correctly, so having controllers dictating the response to any action and so on. I'd think about using Observers to help by having your views observe your models and controllers observe your views (to get events and so on.) Unit-testing this then becomes quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure anything like this exist, as mentioned by previous poster, you just follow the principles of the pattern. However, look at [J2ME Polish](http://www.enough.de/), it's a very nice framework which makes your life with mobile java much easier. Particularly strong features they offer is the usage of CSS for displays - this gives you pretty good "V" part in MVC pattern.

Comment: take a look at LWUIT as well which is supported by Sun and has some good examples with it